# Can't match types with head and ++

Tags: function, haskell, types

I'm a complete beginner at Haskell (and functional programming). I've run into this problem when trying a pretty simple piece of code:

```
Ciphers.hs:24:25:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘Bool’ with actual type ‘[Char]’
    In the expression: sChars ++ (head c)
```

and

```
Ciphers.hs:24:41:
    Couldn't match type ‘Char’ with ‘[Char]’
    Expected type: [[Char]]
      Actual type: Cipher
```

This is the code I'm trying to execute:

```
--Datatype for a cipher
type Cipher = String

validateCipher :: Cipher -> Bool
validateCipher ciph = 
    if((length ciph) /= 26)then 
        False
    else if(let savedChars = "" in vCiph ciph savedChars)then
        True
    else
        False

vCiph :: Cipher -> String -> Bool
vCiph c sChars = 
    if(elem (head c) sChars)then
        False
    else if(length c == 0)then 
        True
    else
        sChars ++ (head c)
        vCiph (tail c) sChars
```

So it's really the last two lines that are causing problems, and I can't figure out why. Honestly, I'm not even sure why the expected type is bool in the first one, why the compiler's column numbers don't match up with Notepad++'s or whether or not I'm allowed to have two lines of code following an else statement.

Comment: Trying to figure out what `sChars ++ (head c) vCiph (tail c) sChars` is even supposed to mean.  That's a single expression, the line break doesn't mean anything.

Comment: Oh, really? I genuinely mean it when I say I'm a complete Haskell noob, I'd expected the line break to seperate it to two statements in lieu of a ; (like every other language). Those lines are meant to add the first character to a list of saved characters and then recurse, the point is to check that the cipher only contains one of each letter in the alphabet.

Comment: Oh, you're absolutely right that a line break does separate statements in Haskell.  You can also use an explicit `;` if necessary.  However, you're not writing any statements--you're writing pure functions.

Comment: Perhaps if you tell us what the code is supposed to do, we can help with that.  It's rather difficult to guess what code is supposed to do just by looking at it.

Comment: That's fair enough. The code is meant to define a Cipher type (functionally identical to a String, wasn't my choice), then validateCipher checks that is contains every letter of the alphabet once and only once. I've done this through first checking it has length 26 then running a recursive function (vCiph) that is meant to check whether the first letter in the cipher has already been stored in an array (savedChars). If it has then the cipher isn't valid (contains multiple of the same letter), if it hasn't then it adds it to the list and recurses with the tail until the cipher is empty or wrong

Comment: a much simpler check then the current validation would be `vCiph = (['a'..'z'] ==) . sort)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, there's the "super easy" way of doing things.

```
import Data.List

type Cipher = String

validateCipher :: Cipher -> Bool
validateCipher c = sort c == ['a'..'z']
```

Then there's a fix for what you were trying to do:

```
type Cipher = String

validateCipher :: Cipher -> Bool
validateCipher ciph = length ciph == 26 && vCiph ciph ""

vCiph :: Cipher -> String -> Bool
vCiph "" _ = True
vCiph (c:cs) prev
  | elem c prev  = False
  | otherwise    = vCiph cs (c:prev)
```

A few things I noticed in your code:

- The code checks if `head c` is in `sChars` and afterwards checks if `c` is empty.  But if `c` is empty, then it's too late, because `head c` throws an exception.
- The code `sChars ++ (head c)` doesn't modify `sChars`.  It creates a new list.
- The code `sChars ++ (head c)` is a type error because `head c` is a `Char` and `++` requires that both sides be `[Char]`.

The new version accomplishes things with pattern matching: the pattern `(c:cs)` splits the argument into the head and tail for you, so you don't have to call `head` and `tail` explicitly.  The pattern `""` will match the empty string, so you don't have to test `length c == 0`.

Here is a style fixup, addressing your concern about having `Cipher` be a `String`:

```
newtype Cipher = Cipher String

validateCipher :: Cipher -> Bool
validateCipher (Cipher ciph) = length ciph == 26 && vCiph ciph ""
  where
    vCiph :: String -> String -> Bool
    vCiph "" _ = True
    vCiph (c:cs) prev
      | elem c prev  = False
      | otherwise    = vCiph cs (c:prev)
```

Using `newtype` instead of `type` makes it so that `Cipher` is no longer a `String`, as far as the type system is concerned.  Think of it as a box with a string inside it.  It is *almost* the same thing as `data Cipher = Cipher String` except for edge cases.

Making `vCiph` part of `validateCipher` makes it clear that `vCiph` has no business being called from other functions.

Comment: Wow, if I could give that answer more than +1 accepted, I would. I think it's taught me more in one page than I've learnt in several weeks. Thank you so so much!